# Is it possible to get NDC of a point behind the view with perspective projection?

Tags: opengl, 3d

I want to get [normalized device coordinates (NDC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clip_coordinates) of a point that is in view/world space by projecting it using a perspective projection matrix, which I use it to get screen position afterwards. A common issue with this approach is that points behind the view appears to be on front of the view after the homogeneous division, because `w` is negative behind the view, after dividing xyz it will invert the actual position (even if I invert again the position, it appears to be a bit off the actual view position).

So I was thinking if there is another way to get the NDC coordinates even if it's behind the view, every source I find always say to clip the homogeneous position (`-w <= xyz <= w`) before dividing it to get the NDC, but I wanted the actual non-clipped screen position for a line shader.

Is there someway to get the actual NDC position of a point that is behind the view with a projection matrix? Even if just `xy` components are correct, which is what I need.

Comment: "*I wanted the actual non-clipped screen position for a line shader.*" That's not a thing that exists. If it's outside of the clipping region, then it has no position on the screen; the clipping region is what *defines* "on the screen".

Comment: I mean something like (0.0, 0.0, -2.0) in ndc would be in the center of the viewport, but would be behind the clip space, but with the perspective projection, there isn't any position that would be projected into this position as expected. It works for something like (2.0, 0.0, 0.5), because the point would be in the far-right portion of the viewport, outside the view, and with the perspective matrix there is a point that would be projected correctly into this point.

Comment: Also with a orthogonal projection matrix the problem goes completely away, because there isn't any perspective division, the point will always be correct, regardless it is behind the view, beyond the left/right/top/bottom/near/far planes, etc. It will always project the point and I can get the correct screen position even if outside the screen, which is what I need for my line shader.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a "mirror" projection matrix, placing it's near plane to the near plane of the original projection matrix, but looking backwards to the view, so I can use this matrix when the point is behind the view near plane to get the screen position, then just invert it back. Something like [this image](https://imgur.com/a/Ab5n5jJ)

Comment: The big question to me would be: what do you actually need this for. To me, this sounds a lot like an XY problem. "but with the perspective projection, there isn't any position that would be projected into this position as expected." so what would you _expect_ here?  The perspective projection is just the intersection of the line defined by the projection center and the point with some image plane. And doing the math will exactly yield that result for any point in front of _or_ behind the projection center (just not on the same plane as the center, as there is no intersection)

Comment: That the xy position is inverted for points behind the camera is the correct behavior; this is how perspective projections work, and it's unclear why you're trying to 'fix' this.

Comment: Trying to give more context to my application:
I'm creating a line shader with fixed width that works both for orthogonal and perspective projection, the vertex shader receives point A and B in world coordinates to build the line from those points. The idea is to project both points to screen space, get the tangent of this line to place the vertices according to the width of the line and output to `gl_Position`. For the fragment shader, it's simply a capsule cutoff shader to give rounded caps at the both ends of the line, so I need the length and width of the line from the vertex shader.

Comment: I'm creating this shader for both single line segments and for poly-lines, when clipping for a single segment, it works just fine, but for polylines I need information of the previous/next points of the segment too, so those extra points would also be clipped and would give a incorrect tangent for the polyline joints. So the idea is to not clip any line segment at all, so I can calculate the tangents of the line in screen space correctly, that's why I need actual screen position for points behind the view without clipping. I hope this clarify my situation.

Comment: But it's ok, if really isn't possible I can deal with that, the original question is if it's possible to get actual ndc coordinates of points behind the view with perspective projection, if isn't then I can find another way in my line shader.

Comment: It is possible to get NDC coordinates of points behind the camera -- you've already done that but they turned out to be not useful. As an extreme case, imagine that the line starts in front of the camera and ends on the focal plane. You'll get a division by zero when calculating the NDC. But you'd need to be able to render such lines anyway -- right? I'm a bit lost in your detailed description of how you're trying to draw those lines, but my impression is that your approach isn't quite right in the first place.

Comment: From what I understand, you should instead clip the AB segment in clip-space to the camera frustum, just like opengl does that. Then you'd generate a triangle mesh covering the thick 'capsule'. This would be done in the geometry shader. The fragment shader would work entirely in screen space after that. I recommend that you ask a new question about drawing a thick line with round caps, showing what you have so far, and including a image of the desired result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248666/discussion-between-ghsoares-and-yakov-galka).